# IndexError: list index out of range in Reversal of arrays

Tags: python, list

I am trying to reverse arrays in groups. I have wasted more than half an hour finding the problem but not able to figure out how is ***index is out of range***.
Here is my code:

```
def rev(A,S,N):
    start=S
    end=N

    while start<end:
        A[start],A[end]=A[end],A[start]   #error here
        start+=1
        end-=1
    return A


def reverseInGroups(A,N,K):
    #Your code here
    rev(A,0,K)
    rev(A,K,N)    #error here
    return A
```

Here is the error I am getting

[image: Here is the error I am getting]

Sample Input 1 : N=5 K=3 A= [1,2,3,4,5]
Sample Output 1 : 3 2 1 5 4

Sample Output 2  N= 8 K=3 A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
Sample Output 2 : 3 2 1 6 5 4 8 7

[For more information please visit this link](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/reverse-array-in-groups0255/1/?track=ppc-arrays&batchId=221)

Comment: how do you call it with what kind of array? or do you mean list? `arraylist` is not a pythonic thing I know of - probably the wrong tag

Comment: How big is A and how much is N?

Comment: Remember that list indexes stop at `len(l) - 1`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. How do you call these functions? The problem is probably in the start and end indices you provide. Also, you should use expressive variable names (and please respect the convention of writing them lowercase).

Comment: i suggest `def rev(a,start,end):`, no need to use unclear names just to change them on the 1st line

Comment: @PatrickArtner Sorry, I used that tag by mistake.

Comment: @Błotosmętek I have updated the description and the link to the question to the link is given below. Please go through it. Thank you

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Please go through the question link. Updated it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
def rev(a,start,end, middle):
    assert 0 <= start <= middle <= end < len(a)
    a[start:middle] = reversed(a[start:middle])
    a[middle:end] = reversed(a[middle:end])
    return a
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use / iterate positions at all - this avoids your error because slicing can handle oversized slices: `[1,2,3,4][2:99]` works w/o error.

```
def rev(data, start, end):
    """Reverses the range start:end (end exclusive) of the given list. 
    No safeguards whatsoever so only use with correct data. Out of bounds 
    is irrelevant due to slices used to reverse."""
    data[start:end] = data[start:end][::-1]  # you need end+1 if you want inclusive
    return data

def reverseInGroups(A,N,K): 
    rev(A,0,K)
    rev(A,K,N) 
    return A


l = list(range(11))

print ( reverseInGroups(l , 8, 3)) # why N (the bigger number) first?
```

to get

```
[2, 1, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 8, 9, 10]
#0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10   # 0-3(exclusive) and 3-8(exclusive) reversed
```

---

To revere all `K` sized groups do

```
def reverseInGroups(A,K):
    pos_at = 0
    while pos_at < len(A):
        rev(A, pos_at, pos_at+K)
        pos_at += K

    return A
```

Comment: Worked like Charm sir. Thank you so much for helping me out. I don't know why was I complicating it with loops and all.

Comment: Sir, your code has helped me but still not able to crack logic for the 3rd test case. Can you please go through the question link in the description?